# I want to get a file with endingstring.json in batch file

Tags: batch-file

Want to get batch file having the extension or with starting string "xyz".

And want to create variable of that file so i can use that variable.

```
set /p pathName=Enter The Value:%=%
@echo %pathName%
if exist {%pathName%\*.json} (
   echo "gaurav"
) else (
    echo "not exist"
)
python dtz/manage.py loaddata %pathName%\*.json
pause
```

It is unable to find *.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set /p pathName=Enter The Value:
for /R %pathName% %%f in (*.json) do (
python dtz/manage.py loaddata "%%f"
)
```

This will execute the python script for every json file in the input folder.